# How to create a custom BottomNavigationBar in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

So I have this design from Comida and their bottomnavbar is quite nice. I've tried the material BottomNavigationBar. Here's the code

```
bottomNavigationBar: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0, top: 5.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: AppColors.primaryColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topRight: Radius.circular(15.0),
          topLeft: Radius.circular(15.0),
        ),
      ),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topRight: Radius.circular(15.0),
          topLeft: Radius.circular(15.0),
        ),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          onTap: onTabTapped,
          currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: '',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag_outlined),
              label: '',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              label: '',
            ),
          ],
          backgroundColor: AppColors.primaryColor,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
          unselectedItemColor: AppColors.accentColor,
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

But I there doesn't seem to be a way to transform it to this

[image]

I just started with flutter and it's going OK but this has got me stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for something like this, [flutter_snake_navigationbar](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_snake_navigationbar), second demo is similar to yours

[UPDATED]

```
bottomNavigationBar: SnakeNavigationBar.color(
        behaviour: snakeBarStyle,
        snakeShape: snakeShape,
        shape: bottomBarShape,
        padding: padding,

        ///configuration for SnakeNavigationBar.color
        snakeViewColor: selectedColor,
        selectedItemColor:
            snakeShape == SnakeShape.indicator ? selectedColor : null,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.blueGrey,

        ///configuration for SnakeNavigationBar.gradient
        // snakeViewGradient: selectedGradient,
        // selectedItemGradient: snakeShape == SnakeShape.indicator ? selectedGradient : null,
        // unselectedItemGradient: unselectedGradient,

        showUnselectedLabels: showUnselectedLabels,
        showSelectedLabels: showSelectedLabels,

        currentIndex: _selectedItemPosition,
        onTap: (index) => setState(() => _selectedItemPosition = index),
        items: [
          const BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.notifications), label: 'tickets'),
          const BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(CustomIcons.calendar), label: 'calendar'),
          const BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(CustomIcons.home), label: 'home'),
          const BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(CustomIcons.podcasts), label: 'microphone'),
          const BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(CustomIcons.search), label: 'search')
        ],
        selectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
        unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
      ),

...

snakeBarStyle = SnakeBarBehaviour.pinned;
          snakeShape = SnakeShape.circle;
          padding = EdgeInsets.zero;
          bottomBarShape = RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: _borderRadius);
```

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Thanks for the reminder, solution updated!